# gtkmm builder from glade file doesn't work

Tags: c++, glade, gtkmm

My gtkmm program won't show any windows. Compile works fine. These are the messages I get when running:

```
(process:2312): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.24.1/gobject    
/gtype.c:2706: You forgot to call g_type_init()
(process:2312): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 
`initialization_value != 0' failed
(process:2312): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_newv: assertion 
`G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

Code is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder =   
         Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("basic.glade");
    Gtk::Window* pMyWindow = 0;
    builder->get_widget("window1", pMyWindow);
    pMyWindow->show();
}
```

It doesn't matter if basic.glade is a valid file or does not exist. I tried with the whole path file instead of basic.glade.
When I debug it, I realize that the program never gets out of that builder first line. It's like it keeps running, so when I pause the only process, either will be at `g_once_init_enter_impl()` or at `g_slist_find()` (being called by the former).
So I don't ever see any window (because it never gets to that `pMyWindow->show()` line)

Comment: Quick question, do you have to destroy (free the memory) of the window at all in main?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following line as your first line in `main`:

```
Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
```

According to the [Gtkmm Hello World tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.0/sec-helloworld.html.en):

> First we instantiate an object called kit. This is of type Gtk::Main. Every gtkmm program must have one of these.

This object is the responsible to initialize all the GTK+ library, that includes a call to the  `g_type_init` function your error talk about.

Of course, you can use any name you like instead of `kit`.

UPDATE: Oh, and you should call to:

```
Gtk::Main::run();
```

Or equivalently:

```
kit.run();
```

as kindly noted by Erandros in the comment. Without it the program will finish immediatley. It will issue a `gtk_main()` call that will run the main loop.

Comment: In order to run the GUI, please add `kit.run()` so I mark this as correct.